# Device Orientation in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, camera, windows-phone-8

I want to rotate the Image based on the device orientation in Windows Phone 8 while taking the snap using PhotoCaptureDevice option.

When the Device orientation is

```
LandscapeLeft  - Image to be rotated to -90
LandscapeRight - Image to be rotated to 90
```

But there is no option to find the device orientation in the Windows Phone 8 . Could you please anyone help me on this ?

Comment: Hi David, Can you explain how you fix the issue. Mainly how you identify Landscape,LandscapeLeft,LandscapeRight,Portrait,PortraitDown,PortraitUp etc orientations.

Comment: You can use the first answer that helped me to resolve the problem..

Comment: ie not my question, How you handled the flat orientation,for eg device lies in a table with the orientations Portrait and landscape

Comment: you can contact me through nicedavid60@gmail.com for further information of through my facebook profile https://www.facebook.com/davidc1987

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the acceleration sensor readings and then take the atan2 as follows:

```
angle = Math.Atan2(-x,y) * 180.0 / Math.PI;
```

where "angle" is the device orientation relativ to the default portrait orientation.

Comment: Just to flesh out above to save others the hassle, you need:
var accel = new Microsoft.Devices.Sensors.Accelerometer;
var curr = accel.CurrentValue.Acceleration;
var x = curr.X;
var y = curr.Y;

PS thanks OP

Answer (score -2):

You need to override the [PhoneApplicationPage.OnOrientationChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.onorientationchanged%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method to get notifications of when the orientation changes. You will need to make sure that your page supports the various orientations that you need first.

Then you can change your image orientation based on this.

Comment: I dont want to work based on the Page orientation. I need to work based on the Orientation of the PhotoCaptureDevice..

Comment: Hmm - these are the same (apart from you can't detect if you're in portrait and upside down). You're displaying your image in a page, correct?

Comment: Yes i display image. I need to rotate the image based on the orientation of the device.

Comment: Or else you could use the EXIF data from the camera once the photo is taken - did you see http://www.softwareisinthedetails.com/2012/11/windows-phone-8-photo-orientation-exif-bug.html for instance?