# Windows Phone 8 get device orientation

Tags: sensors, windows-phone-8, device-orientation

For a Windows Phone application I need the device orientation (e.g. 0,90,180, and 270 degrees) but the layout is fixed to portrait.
At the moment I am calculating the orientation from the acceleration sensor readings using the atan2(-accleeration_x,acceleration_y). Is there a build-in method to get the device orientation instead of manually using the acceleration sensor?

Regards,

**Edit:** someone asked a similar question almost the same time here: [Device Orientation in Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740443/device-orientation-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: How does your question differ from the previous one? Did you check the answer to the previous question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device Orientation in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740443/device-orientation-in-windows-phone-8)