# WP7 Detect the screen orientation change when SupportedOrientations="Portrait"

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to keep the orientation of my page always the same, for example SupportedOrientations="Portrait". But I want to detect the screen orientation change. is it possible?
I tired OrientationChanged="PhoneApplicationPage_OrientationChanged", but it doesn't work. Do I have to use accelerometer or there is a easier way to detect it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Device Orientation in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13740443/device-orientation-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: Yes, you have to use the accelerometer.

Answer (score 0):

@heavyauto

[Page orientations](http://dotneteers.net/blogs/vbandi/archive/2011/03/08/handling-wp7-orientation-changes-via-visual-states.aspx)  In Windows Phone 7 ..Maybe this is Use full to You